# UIScrollviewController Not Working As Expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am implementing a simple scrollview within my app. However, the view will not scroll at all. Only the "biography" subview scrolls within it's own view, not relative to the parent view. Below is the implementation file of the parent view.

```
#import "ProfileViewController.h"

@interface ProfileViewController ()

@end

@implementation ProfileViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Profile";
    self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbarviewimage"];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    self.scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 640);

    UIImageView *myView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbarviewimage"]];
    [myView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    myView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 114);

    UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 140, 280, 40)];
    nameLabel.text = @"Name: Jon Doe";

    UILabel *cityLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 200, 280, 40)];
    cityLabel.text = @"From: Los Angeles";

    UITextView *biography = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 260, 300, 180)];
    biography.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15];
    biography.editable = NO;
    biography.text = @"sample bio";

    UILabel *memberSinceLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 600, 280, 40)];
    memberSinceLabel.text = @" 2016";

    [self.scrollView addSubview:myView];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:nameLabel];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:cityLabel];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:biography];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:memberSinceLabel];

    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView ];

}

@end
```

Comment: Is the screen height 640 or more? If so, there's nothing to scroll.

Comment: where is you delegate ? `self.scrollView.delegate = self`

Answer (score 0):

You have `UIScrollView` of height 640 and talk about there contents.

1.`myView :` **YPos** = 20, **Height** = 114 i.e upto 134 Y-point there is myview.

2. `nameLabel :` **YPos** = 140, **Height** = 40 i.e `nameLabel`starts from **140** to **180**.
3. `cityLabel :` **YPos** = 200, **Height** = 40 i.e `cityLabel` is from **200** to **240**.
4. `biography :` **YPos** = 260, **Height** = 180 i.e `biography` is from **260** to **440**.
5. Now, `memberSinceLabel` is starting from **600** so there is nothing between 
   **440** to **600**.
   `memberSinceLabel` is from **600** to **640**.

I have discussed pixels of each and every components which is in `scrollView`.
As it is measured you have finely spread your components within `scrollView`.

But according to **Apple Documentation** the scrolling property of `UIScrollView` is depends on the contents size i.e. if the content size of scrollview is greater than `UIscrollview` size then and only then scrollview scrolls in that particular  direction.

For example, `UITextView` has the property of `UIScrollView` but if its content is greater then  `UItextView`size then only you can scroll contents of otherwise you can not scroll.

Same here is happpening with you, your content size is equal to the `scrollView` size that means you can see all the  contents without scrolling that's why here is it not scrolling.

And always remember to bind `delegate` and  `dataSource` and add them with your class like this `@interface ProfileViewController ()<UIScrollViewDelegate>`